# std::is_same<...> rejects my templated iterator::value_type argument

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20

I wrote a templated `join` function for `std::string` containers based on arbitrary iterators and I want to `static_assert` that the `value_type` of iterators (i.e. the type of the value pointed to by the iterator) is indeed `std::string` (I guess it's a bit redundant but I'd like to make this work...).

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace util {

    template<typename iterator>
    std::string join(iterator begin, iterator end, const std::string& delimiter, const bool discard_empty = false) {
#if 1
        static_assert(std::is_same<iterator::value_type, std::string>::value, "bad iterator; iterator::value_type is not std::string");
#endif
        if (begin == end)
            return "";

        std::string joined = *begin;
        for (iterator it = ++begin; it != end; it++) {
            if (!discard_empty || !it->empty())
                joined += delimiter + *it;
        }
        return joined;
    }
}

#include <set>
#include <vector>
/*
    manual verification:
*/
static_assert(std::is_same<std::vector<std::string>::iterator::value_type, std::string>::value, "");    //pass!
static_assert(std::is_same<std::set<std::string>::iterator::value_type, std::string>::value, "");       //pass!

void foo() {

    std::vector<std::string> v{
        "hello",
        "world",
    };

    std::string sv = util::join(v.begin(), v.end(), " ");

    std::set<std::string> s{
        "hello",
        "world",
    };

    std::string ss = util::join(s.begin(), s.end(), " ");
}
```

`std::is_same<...>` rejects my templated `iterator::value_type` type, why?

Compiler error (MSVC):

> std::is_same' : 'std::_Vector_iteratorstd::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>::value_type' n'est pas un argument de type modèle valide pour le paramètre '_Ty1'.

Comment: You're just missing `typename` before `iterator::value_type`.

Comment: I don't understand why `typename` is required here, but yes that was it - thank you for the quick fix (again..)

Comment: @康桓瑋 what actually *is* `iterator::value_type` here if I don't prefix it with `typename`? (what will the compiler parse it *as*?)

Comment: it could be anything. It could be a static member of type `int`. `typename` tells the compiler that it is a type

Comment: But `std::is_same` expects a type and there can be no specialization that expects a non-type. So `iterator::value_type` must be a type. I wonder why C++20 needs `typename` in this context.

Comment: @Evg, The template needs to be parsed before instantiation. Something being a type vs. a value can change the parse entirely (e.g., with `T` unknown, `T* p;` could be an expression or introduce another name).

Comment: @chris That's true, but in C++20 rules have been relaxed - `typename` is no longer required if there is no ambiguity. I don't see how `iterator::value_type` could be a non-type inside `std::is_same`.

Comment: @Evg, I guess it could if more rules were added to look farther away, but I think the paper focused on places where something is _always_ a type rather than getting the parser to do yet more lookup to see how to parse the next piece.